# sharepoint 2010 - get name of custom site template

Tags: feature, site-template

1. How to get the complete name of the feature [see last 2 name , basically they are custom created templates]
2. Can i change the name which is basically the feature id with the custom name ?

[image: Site Template]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
get-spwebtemplate | format-table name, title
```

it should work

and for the 2., take a look in the webtemp.xml file. The title should be there :

```
<Templates xmlns:ows="Microsoft SharePoint">
<Template Name="TemplateName"
          ID="10000">
    <Configuration ID="0"
                   Title="Template title"
                   Hidden="FALSE"
                   ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/CPVW.gif"
                   Description=""
                   DisplayCategory="My corp"/>
</Template>
</Templates>
```

Comment: worked as required !!!!